# Operational amplifier conversion of a sinusoidal wave

Tags: operational-amplifier, wave

Ok guys my question is: Is possible to turn a sinusoidal wave into a square wave with just an operational amplifier?

Comment: Yes. Comparator.

Comment: You could have the gain set so high that it hits the rail at very small input voltages (sort of like a comparator!)

Comment: A square wave has infinite harmonics so no, in reality a square wave is impossible to generate but maybe if you lowered your standards a tad?

Comment: It depends on the quality needed for the square wave. What is your frequency and how fast a risetime and falltime do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes -- with caveats.  If you really mean *just* an op-amp, because of noise, you'll likely see dirty transitions, maybe with some bounce,  if you use the op-amp open loop as a comparator.

You can get rid of this if you use some resistors to provide some hysteresis, by way of a bit of positive feedback.

Op-amps are not optimized to function this way.  There may be some stickiness to overcome saturation (i.e., "lockup"), and some other issues like low slew.  If you need great performance, you should use a real comparator.

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically no, at least for real op amps.

The problem is that a square wave theoretically has zero rise and fall times, and real op amps don't. Granted, you can get op amps with very high slew rates, but never infinite.

Of course, real square waves don't have zero rise and fall times, either.

So you should probably do a little thinking as to exactly what you're asking.